# Fluent Validation in Razor Page

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, error-handling, razor-pages, fluentvalidation

Based on this [page](https://www.tutlane.com/tutorial/aspnet-mvc/fluent-validation-in-aspnet-mvc-with-example) I am trying to make a razor page that used fluent validation. It seemed to have checked but I'm not sure why the error message will not display.

Here is what I have done so far:

cshtml.cs:

```
CreateCommandValidator CreateValidator = new CreateCommandValidator();
var createCheck = CreateValidator.Validate(NewItem);
foreach (ValidationFailure fail in createCheck.Errors)
{
     ModelState.AddModelError(fail.PropertyName, fail.ErrorMessage);
}
return Page();
```

cshtml:

```
<label class="col-form-label">Name</label>
<input asp-for="NewItem.Name" type="text" class="form-control mb-2"/>
<span asp-validation-for="NewItem.Name" class="text-danger"></span>
```

CreateCommandValidator:

```
RuleFor
     (Item => Item.Name)
     .NotEmpty().WithMessage("The name cannot be empty")
     .Length(1, 100);
```

The ValidationFailure is able to detect the error message but not sure why it won't be displayed out on the page. Any ideas why? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please upvote and mark as answer if my answer solved your problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The ValidationFailure is able to detect the error message but not sure
>   why it won't be displayed out on the page. Any ideas why?

That is because your key name of `data-valmsg-for` is `NewItem.Name`.

Your cshtml file below:

```
<span asp-validation-for="NewItem.Name" class="text-danger"></span>
```

would generate the html in the browser like below:

```
<span data-valmsg-for="NewItem.Name" class="text-danger field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
```

1.The first way,you could change the key name like below:

```
ModelState.AddModelError("NewItem.Name", fail.ErrorMessage);
```

2.The second way,if you do not want to add the key name manually,you could install `FluentValidation.AspNetCore` package and change your code like below:

```
CreateCommandValidator CreateValidator = new CreateCommandValidator();
var createCheck = CreateValidator.Validate(NewItem);

//AddToModelState(ModelStateDictionary modelState, string prefix);
createCheck.AddToModelState(ModelState, "NewItem");

return Page();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have scripts for unobtrusive validation if they are not already there.

**Example**

View(cshtml):

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Log in";
}
<section>
    <div class="container">

    </div>
</section>


@section Scripts {
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.17.0/jquery.validate.min.js"
            crossorigin="anonymous"
            integrity="sha256-F6h55Qw6sweK+t7SiOJX+2bpSAa3b/fnlrVCJvmEj1A=">
    </script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/3.2.11/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"
            crossorigin="anonymous"
            integrity="sha256-9GycpJnliUjJDVDqP0UEu/bsm9U+3dnQUH8+3W10vkY=">
    </script>
}
```

The shared layout(_Layout.cshtml) should have scripts section

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />


 </head>
<body>
    <div class="main-container">
        @RenderBody()
    </div>



    @RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, all of these are already included and yet the Error Message was not displaying.

Comment: @ZorevGnoz, try the accepted answer. Also make sure your span element has proper closing tag like "<span asp-validation-for="NewItem.Name" class="text-danger"></span>" .  Not like "<span asp-validation-for="NewItem.Name" class="text-danger"/>"